# after jquery ajax call, i want to redirect to another page and want to print returned json data on that page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have a search button on index.aspx page, and when i click on it, jquery ajax is fired and json data is returned in 'success:function(jsondata)' block. now i want to go to search.aspx page and print this data there. i am new on jquery.Thanks

```
//jquery code on index.aspx page
$('#searchsubmit').on('click', function (e) {





                var key = $("#searchbox").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "search.aspx/getResult",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'searchkey': key }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (jsondata) {
                        window.location.href = "http://localhost:50165/search.aspx";
                    // How to access json data on search.aspx

                        });




                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the data along in the query string and print on that page.

`window.location.href = "http://localhost:50165/search.aspx?data=datareturned";`

Or pass the key to the new page and have it load the correct response.

`window.location.href = "http://localhost:50165/search.aspx?key=searchkey";`

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are initiating 2 requests to the server 
first is to get data and the second is the redirect itself

Why do you want to do this in 2 steps?

You should use a `GET` instead of `POST` 
i.e. in this case redirect the user to `search.aspx?searchkey=someVal`

like this:

```js
$('#searchsubmit').on('click', function (e) {

  var key = $("#searchbox").val();
  window.location.href = `http://localhost:50165/search.aspx?searchkey=${key}`
});
```

To retrieve the query string param in the server side:

```
string searchkey = Request.QueryString["searchkey"] ?? string.Empty;
```